# Can I do a foreign key lookup while importing data into SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms, sql-import-wizard

**Background**

I have a spreadsheet of data that I'm importing into SQL Server 2005. I'm using the Import Wizard in Management Studio to do this.

**Problem**

I'm importing the data into Table A. Table A has a foreign key reference to Table B. My spreadsheet contains a value in Table B and I need the key for that value so I can put it into Table A. Is there a way to do this lookup as a part of the import wizard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The import wizard should allow you to create your own query for import rather than its own.

So, with that, you can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO tableA(c1, c2, c3)
SELECT c1, c2, TableB.pk 
FROM 
  inputtable 
  INNER JOIN TableB ON TableB.anotherfield = inputtable.bcol
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have standard or enterprise version, you can use SSIS (BI development studio) to edit the package the wizard creates. Use **Lookup** transformation to get the key. If you happen to have trouble with data types (frequent when using Excel source) use **Data Conversion** transformation after the Excel source,